# Why do I have these arp cache entries, for addresses way outside my network?

Tags: networking, fedora, arp

```
$ ip -4 neigh show dev eno1
209.132.181.16  FAILED
152.19.134.142  FAILED
85.236.55.6  FAILED
152.19.134.198  FAILED
8.43.85.67  FAILED
140.211.169.206  FAILED
```

How could these weird ip neighbour (ARP) entries be appearing on my Ethernet interface?

`eno1` is an Ethernet interface.  It is not currently connected.  Based on `journalctl -b | grep eno1`, I do not think I have connected it at all during this boot!  I do not use a static IP.  I have not changed my IP settings manually during this boot.  The network settings are all managed by NetworkManager.  I have connected only to my home networks, which use addresses in the private range 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 only.

For example on my current wireless connection, I see that my address is 172.16.8.139/24.  That says the network prefix is 24 bits, and so ARP resolution should be limited to the range 172.16.8.0 - 172.16.8.255.

```
$ ip -4 addr show dev wlp2s0
4: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.16.8.139/24 brd 172.16.8.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 39441sec preferred_lft 39441sec

$ ip -4 neigh show dev wlp2s0
172.16.8.1 lladdr 74:44:01:86:42:d6 REACHABLE
```

---

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Fedora release 29 (Twenty Nine)
$ rpm -q NetworkManager dhcp-client
NetworkManager-1.12.6-5.fc29.x86_64
dhcp-client-4.3.6-28.fc29.x86_64
```

My router is OpenWRT 18.06.1, so the DHCP server is `dnsmasq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What are the "neighbours" called? - my first idea.

```
$ ip -r -4 neigh show dev eno1
proxy01.fedoraproject.org  FAILED
vm3.fedora.ibiblio.org  FAILED
6-55-236-85.rev.customer-net.de  FAILED
vm18.fedora.ibiblio.org  FAILED
proxy13-rdu02.fedoraproject.org  FAILED
proxy14.fedoraproject.org  FAILED
proxy09.fedoraproject.org  FAILED
```

It is trying to connect to a Fedora-specific service.  I.e. the system uses some network service.  Fedora is providing it.  (And/or ibiblio.org are donating service to Fedora, using a specific host name, etc.)  These hosts are most likely primarily providing some Web service (HTTP / HTTPS).  "proxy" in a hostname tends to mean some form of Web proxy, and these can be used as a front end for various reasons e.g. caching or load balancing.

### Why would I see such out-of-range ARP entries? - the biggest question.

I found the answer on StackOverflow: [Why ARP requests a non-local address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404382/why-arp-requests-a-non-local-address)

When one interface has no addresses/routes at all, but you explicitly tell Linux to transmit using it, Linux will assume your target address is on-link.[*]  There is a comment about this feature in the [kernel source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.0/source/net/ipv4/route.c#L2431).  Here is a clear example:

```
$ sudo traceroute --udp -i eno1 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
^C
$ ip neigh show dev eno1 | grep 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8  INCOMPLETE
```

I expect I am seeing these attempted connections due to NetworkManager.  I don't have any other software which is likely to try to contact a Web service using a specific interface.  (Note that this operation requires privilege.  In the example above, I had to use `sudo` to run traceroute through a specific interface).

NetworkManager uses a web service to check internet connectivity, and to detect captive portals.  This is mentioned in the CONNECTIVITY section of [`man NetworkManager.conf`](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html).

It looks like NetworkManager has been checking this interface, despite knowing  there is no connection on it :-).

---

[*] This means the sender IP address in the [ARP packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol#Packet_structure), is taken from a different interface :-).  Or if I shut down my other interfaces (WiFi and `virbr0`), the ARP request uses 0.0.0.0 as the source address :-).  I tested this using `tcpdump`, and a second computer connected directly with an ethernet cable.